# Responsive Website design issues

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to design a layout for the first time, the design should be responsive.
After giving the body and html`height : 100%` I am not able to click on my menu. Before that change responsive menu was working fine.

If I remove section and footer from the html and remove the `height : 100%` of body and html tag. I am able click on the menu. Can any one help me out to fix this issue. 
Two issues
1. Responsive menu not able to click
2. Footer is not at the bottom.

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <input type ="checkbox" id ="menuToggle" checked ="checked"/>
            <label for ="menuToggle" class ="menu-icon">&#9776</label>
            <div id ="logo">Heading</div>
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and rem Ipsum has been 
            </p>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <div id="footer">
                <p>
                    Copyright © 2016 by sample.com. All Rights Reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

css code

```
* {
    padding: 0;margin: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
header {
    width: 100%;height: 100px;margin: auto;z-index: 99;background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
section {
    height : 100%;top:50px;position:relative;
}
footer {
    width : 100%;background:#034676;height:20px;
    bottom:0px;position:relative;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;color: blue;font-size: 14px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#logo {
    float: left;line-height: 50px;color: #147DC2;font-size: 30px;
}
header nav {
    width: 100%;text-align: center;
}
header nav ul {
    float: left;line-height: 50px;
}
header nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
header nav a {
    padding: 10px;color: #f1e7d1;
}
header nav a:hover {
    background: #032976;color: #FFF;border-radius: 5px;
}
.main-nav {
    background: #034676;width: 100%;height: 50px;position: absolute;top: -101px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}
.menu-icon {
    float : right;padding : 10px 20px;background : #034676;
    color : #FFF;cursor : pointer;border-radius : 5px;margin : 5px 5px 0 0;
}
#menuToggle {
    display: none;
}
#menuToggle:checked ~ .main-nav {
    position: absolute;top: 101px;
}

/********Responsive*/
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header nav li {
        display: block;
    }
    header nav a {
        display: block;padding :0;border-bottom : 1px solid #040376
    }
    header nav a:hover {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .main-nav {
        top : -350px;height : auto;
    }
    header nav ul {
        float : none;line-height : 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: would be great if you can provide a fiddle

Comment: try replacing height: 100%; to height: auto;

Comment: remove the "z-index: -1" from your main-nav class. You don't need any z-index there according to your current functionality.

Comment: Why do you adding answer by commit instead of adding anwer? I'm a newbie of StackoverFlow ,is that a rule or something?

Comment: no @yaochiqkl. it is not a rule. On the contrary, the rule is to post [answers as "answers"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242768).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the issue one:
You put the z-index equals -1 and that's why link cant be clicked

```
.main-nav {
 z-index: 100;
}
```

About issue 2:
you can't make middle section with equals 100%,that means it will occupy the whole window . Don't set it or set it auto.
You set both of section and footer relative ,so footer can't follow section.

```
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

Default settings will be okay.

Look at this:

```
header {width: 100%;height: 100px;margin: auto;z-index: 99;background: #FFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;}
```

you put the header z-index equals 99 . So nav bar which has smaller z-index(default 0) is underneath header . Set z-index if neccessary rather than set it all the time. :)

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me.. But when we give z-index 100 menu is coming from top of the page. Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1:

Remove the `z-index: -1` from you `.menu-nav` class

Issue 2:

Use `margin-top: 50px` instead of `top: 50px` in `section` tag

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. But when we remove z-index the menu is coming from top of the page.